# how to run linux commands on real server using php

Tags: php, exec

I have created a script in **php** in which i have created a function 
which executes a command using **exec()**. The function is as follows

```
public function tellWhoAmI()
{
return exec('whoami');
}
```

On `localhost` it is working as it should but when **i upload it to the server** the **exec()** does not seem to be working. 
**Question:-**
Do i need to do something else to run this on real server?

Comment: What permissions does the php user have?

Comment: YES! You need to have the autority to do this. So ask your provider for that.

Comment: it may be disabled in your PHP ini on the server, directive disable_function="exec,shell_exec...", or your apache server may be running in safe mode.